# Help accessing Beagle over serial with Minicom/GTKTerm

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to access a brand new Beagle Board from Ubuntu or Mac over serial using the setup seen here: http://specialcomp.com/beagleboard/RevC1.htm

I got Minicom and GTKTerm installed on the Ubuntu box. I set up the correct baud rate, turned off flow control, and have tried ttyUSB0 and ttyS0. Once minicom is configured properly, I should just see the init text from the board appear if I have minicom open in terminal while I plug in the board, correct?

dmesg shows ttyUSB0 on the computer has been connected to ttyS0 on the beagle.

Answer (score 0):

RS-232 ports don't have a common method for indicating the presence of a device; therefore, some sort of "attention" message is required. Try pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Minicom, after plugging in the board.

(There is also no way to see init messages that have been printed before connecting the serial port.)